# Getting value from a function and put it in a input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a slider function, now i'm trying to get the value from that slider in a hidden input field, so that I can use php with it. Anybody got any idea of doing that?

This the slider javascript

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
      //console.log("ready!");

      $(function () {
          var circularSlider = $('#slider').CircularSlider({
              min: 0,
              max: 359,
              value: 0,
              radius: 200,
              labelSuffix: "°",
              slide: function (ui, value) {
                  var colors = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'pink', 'black'];
                  var color = colors[parseInt(value / 60)];
                  ui.find('.jcs').css({'border-color' : color, 'border-width': '50px' });
                  ui.find('.jcs-indicator').css({'background' : color});
                  ui.find('.jcs-value ').css({'background' : color, 'top': '15%', 'left': '17%' });
                  /*ui.next().css({
                      'background': 'linear-gradient(' + value +
                      'deg, white, cornsilk, white)'
                  });*/

              }
          });
          //window.location.href= "mood.php?uid=" .color;
      });

  });
```

here is the html of the slider and the input field

```
<div id="slider"></div>

<button class="moodReady">Ready</button>
<form class="input" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" class="data"/>
</form>
```

Comment: describe what you mean by `use php with it`

Comment: do you need to set value in input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
      //console.log("ready!");

      $(function () {
          var circularSlider = $('#slider').CircularSlider({
              min: 0,
              max: 359,
              value: 0,
              radius: 200,
              labelSuffix: "°",
              slide: function (ui, value) {
                  var colors = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'pink', 'black'];
                  var color = colors[parseInt(value / 60)];
                  ui.find('.jcs').css({'border-color' : color, 'border-width': '50px' });
                  ui.find('.jcs-indicator').css({'background' : color});
                  ui.find('.jcs-value ').css({'background' : color, 'top': '15%', 'left': '17%' });
                  document.getElementById('hiddenValue').value = value;

                  /*ui.next().css({
                      'background': 'linear-gradient(' + value +
                      'deg, white, cornsilk, white)'
                  });*/

              }
          });
          //window.location.href= "mood.php?uid=" .color;
      });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script src="http://toolitup.com/assets/js/circular-slider.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://toolitup.com/assets/css/circular-slider.min.css" />
    
<div id="slider"></div>

<button class="moodReady">Ready</button>
<form class="input" action="" method="post">
    <input id="hiddenValue" type="hidden" class="data"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to set the color var as input value and assuming its the only element with class `data`

you can simply set it like this (shortened your code)

```
  slide: function (ui, value) {
      //...
      var color = colors[parseInt(value / 60)];
      $('.data').val(color);
      //...
  }
```